# Installing MySQL on 64 bit Oracle Linux server

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat, mysql-5.1

I have to install MySQL 5.1.73 in Oracle Linux 5. When I searched the compatible version of MySQL, I found multiple edition of MySQL on [download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#downloads). My LINUX server is 64 bit machine. There are below versions of MySQL 5.1.73 for 64 bit machine:

- MySQL-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar
- MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-test-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-devel-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-client-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-shared-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-community-debuginfo-5.1.73-1.rhel5.i386.rpm
- MySQL-embedded-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-community-debuginfo-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm

  Now, I am totally confused about which file should I download to install MySQL in my LINUX server?  Also, is it possible to get MySQL 5.1.58 community server edition unlike 5.1.73?

Answer (score 1):

I guess `bundle` (first) will install (almost) everything that is below. (Probably what you need)
But if you want only `server` it is `MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm`.

These are not different versions. These are different parts of a big package.

Comment: +1 vote. how to get mysql 5.1.58 for my linux. server?

Comment: Well, if there is no such version in any repos - you need to find a package of this version and manually install it (either from pacakge or source code)